# Create child rows within datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview which populates a number of numeric columns values in rows as standard for a datagridview:

[image: DataGridView Subsection image1]

At the end of the gridview is a text column with a long string of text in it:

[image: DataGridView Subsection image2]

Each comment applies to the data in its respective row.

Is it possible to manipulate the datagridview so:

1. the comment line appears below each row, interspersing each row (and it wrapped)
2. implement a tick box which hides or shows the comments between each row?

An abbreviated version of the code to populate datagridview is as follows:

```
public Form04(System.Windows.Forms.Form parentForm)
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           opener = parentForm;
           dgvForm.DataSource = GetForm();
           dgvForm.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
           DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        }

private DataTable GetForm()
        {
            DataTable dtForm = new DataTable();
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT
                         Date
                        ,Course
                        ,Dist
                        ,Age
                        ,Btn
                        ,Position
                        ,Odds
                        ,Comment
                        FROM [Smartform].[dbo].[Performances]" 
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtForm.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            return dtForm;
        }
```

How can I edit it to achieve the comment in a long (and wrapped string) sitting below the other columns, interspersing each row with a tick-box option to make the comment visible/hidden?

Comment: Use `TemplateField` to customize your row and [bootstrap collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/) to hide/show comment line.

Comment: As an alternative and with a little work, you can get [this Master-Detail](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/835501/Master-Detail-Datagridview) in VB converted to C#. I used [Telerik Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) for the heavy lifting, manually fixed the errors, and had to add my own expand/collapse.png's to the MasterControl.cs [Design] RowHeaderIconList.Images collection.